How to make rigged clothing react to collisions or gravity?
I am trying to model an army ceremonial outfit that has tassels under the epaulets. I would like to know how to make the tassels move naturally, as in when the body moves around, or the arm moves, the tassels interact accordingly. I was following this tutorial on this page here:
How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?
Which kind of gave me something to start with, but i was not too happy with how the rig ended up. It did not react with the body realistically.
Is there a better method of achieving this?
The look i am going for is like how capes, ropes, and sometimes hair is treated in video games. It reacts and flows with wind and the player's body. These tassels are made from curves. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ayq6jr22pwvp7h9/Trouble+shooting.blend/file


Maybe first thing convert to mesh, and also look into tools like Wiggle Bones or Bone Dynamics which will fake the physics with bones? Or simply use Cloth simulation, if it is supposed to interact with the vest, give the vest a Collision physic

You could create 2 spheres around the laces, the small with Collision, the biggest with Cloth, convert your laces to mesh, join them all, give the object a Mesh Deform modifier with the large sphere as Object, click on the Bind button. Assign a vertex group to the top vertices of this sphere, it will be its cloth Pin Group. Parent these objects to the armature bones:

Result:

File: 

I see, i will give this a shot, thank you!

do you mind dropping the .blend? I would like to see how you did this @moonboots

Sure, i've put the link

Thank you, i will study this immensely. @moonboots
